# minimal window manager to enforce visual chroot and exit on application exit

Tags: x11, xorg, raspberry-pi, window-manager

I am trying to have a kiosk style setup on raspberry pi where only one application is available via VNC e.g. gedit or firefox.

Using a guide like this http://gpio.kaltpost.de/?page_id=84 the setup of headless X11 and VNC is easy enough but i am struggling to find a minimal windows manager that i can prevent a user from minimizing the applications main screen and also have a event hook so when the application is closed via it's menu, or crashed i guess, then the windows manager will exit as well, in turn ending the VNC server/session.

Exiting from the application is OK as the x11/vncserver will be managed by a supervisord type process supervisor and will auto restart.

The user should be isolated to the application so the windows manager should allow it's keybindings to be disabled if they allow multiple virtual desktops, or launching a shell, window re-sizing etc.. i.e i want a type of visual chroot.

Can anyone suggest windows manager that supports this feature set and some examples of implementing please ?

Thanks fLo

Comment: I don't understand what you want from a window manager here. Why not run the application full screen, without a window manager? (This is called “kiosk mode”, by the way; a web search for that will give you plenty of tutorials.)

Comment: i tried that first with simple `$startx firefox` but without a window manager you have no title bar, and the mouse didn't work when clicking menus and various other things didn't function. Maybe there is another way to start and application in kiosk mode without window manager where everything functions correctly.. any examples ?

Answer (score 0):

-Yout can try the BlackBox here - http://blackboxwm.sourceforge.net/ - or here -  http://xwinman.org/blackbox.php  is simple and so good!...

Answer (score 0):

turns out [jwm](http://joewing.net/projects/jwm/) does everything i need thanks to most recent release so thanks for looking but will answer my own question.